# Selecting/Inner Joining multiple values from one table into a single row

Tags: t-sql, join, inner-join

I've been searching google all afternoon I'm not even sure how I would word the question I have so that google or bing might understand it. So I have 2 tables(the tables and the database setup were not my doing) one is the details of a product

```
name, value, weight, weight unit of measure id, length, width, height, dimensions unit of measure id, description
```

Then another table with the units of measure and their ID values

eg.

```
id, unit name
1,     cm
2,   inches
3,     lbs
4,     kg
5,    feet
```

I need to select from the products table, but replace the unit of measure ID's with the actual unit of measure text from the other table.

the data looks like

```
sm widgets, $10, 20, 3, 10, 10, 10, 1, small widgets
```

I want the results to come out like

```
sm widget, $10, 20, lbs, 10, 10, 10, cm, small widgets 
lg widget, $15, 50, kg, 10, 10, 10, inches, large widgets
```

thanks for any insight you guys can give me

Comment: Aside: Now once you add a `UnitType`, e.g. `'Length'` or `'Mass'`, to the table of units you can do dimensional analysis! Or at least verify that the unit of weight isn't `'Candlepower'`. (It should really be in another table with a foreign key in the units table. And another table for system of measure, e.g. `'SI'`. Then conversion factors ... .)

Comment: interesting stuff, again its not my database, its developed for us by another company, I'm just writing reports from it, but I get what you're saying, cool stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to join the tables and return the description:

```
select
    p.name, 
    p.value, 
    p.weight, 
    c.[unitname],
    p.length, 
    p.width, 
    p.height, 
    c2.[unitname] as DimensionUnitName, 
    p.[description]
from products p
inner join unitcodetable c
    on c.id = p.[weight unit of measure id]
inner join unitcodetable c2
    on c2.id = p.[dimensions unit of measure id]
```

Comment: Yes this is close but I need the unit of measure twice, your solution only has it once. so the first unit would come back to me correctly but the unit of measure I need for the length width and height will only be an ID number.


if I was to just replace it with `c.[unitname]` I don't think it will work because how do I specify which ID to match with each unitname?

Comment: Oh got you.  Adjusted the answer to join the code table a second time and return the desc column.